How to set specific env config vars after heroku ps:exec?
I'm using heroku ps:exec to get into a dyno. I'd like to run a command, but the command relies on some env config vars that are already set on the application.
Per Heroku's documentation:

The SSH session created by Heroku Exec doesn’t have the config vars
set as environment variables (i.e., env in a session doesn’t list
config vars set by heroku config:set).

How can you get around this? Is it possible to activate specific env vars from the production configuration after you're already in exec mode? I am using Python.
Here's a similar SO post, but the only submitted answer doesn't seem to work with a Python project.

That workflow doesn't make much sense. Specifically, what do you mean by "of course the command relies on some env config vars"? Can you execute your command using heroku run instead?

Thanks and sorry for the slow reply. Yes, heroku run does work and commands thru that will take up the correct env variables! Thanks for pointing that out.

Does that answer your question? Using heroku run instead of heroku exec? I'm still not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish.

It helps me accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish - thanks! I'm still curious why heroku exec would have this limitation and if there's any way to work around it while still using exec, but I am unstuck for my project now at least.

heroku exec logs into a running dyno using SSH. As you noted, these sessions don't have access to config vars by design.
But this isn't the only way to run commands on Heroku. Most of the time, heroku run is a better choice. This creates a one-off dyno that gets discarded when the command finishes running. One-off dynos do have access to your applications's config vars.
The only time I'd reach for heroku exec over heroku run is when I need to access the dyno's local state. Applications run best on Heroku when local state is minimal and dynos can be spun up or down at any time.
